# Slick drop and take throwing error

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.3

I'm learning Play Scala with Slick and run into a problem. The query generated by Slick throws an error when using drop and take (works fine without drop and take, but I need pagination).

```
val categories = TableQuery[Categories]

def list(page: Int = 0, pageSize: Int = 10, orderBy: Int = 1)(implicit s: Session): Page[Category] = {

    val offset = pageSize * page
    val totalRows = count
    /* Error here */
    val result = categories.drop(offset).take(pageSize).list
    /* This works fine */
    /* val result = categories.list */

    Page(result, page, offset, totalRows)
  }
```

The query generated and error stacktrace:

```
[JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT X2.""id"", X2.""name"", X2.""description"" FROM (SELECT X3.""id"" AS ""id"", X3.""name"" AS ""name"", X3.""description"" AS ""description"" FROM ""core_category"" X3 FETCH[*] NEXT 10 ROW ONLY) X2 "; expected "RIGHT, LEFT, FULL, INNER, JOIN, CROSS, NATURAL, ,, WHERE, GROUP, HAVING, UNION, MINUS, EXCEPT, INTERSECT, ORDER, LIMIT, FOR, )"; SQL statement:
select x2."id", x2."name", x2."description" from (select x3."id" as "id", x3."name" as "name", x3."description" as "description" from "core_category" x3 fetch next 10 row only) x2 [42001-175]]
```

Any ideas how could I implement pagination without getting this error?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Slick. You may want to report it to Slick project here: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues

Answer (score 0):

I was importing JdbcDriver instead of personalized drivers (H2Driver in my case) to get the correct dialect.